# How can I replace certain string in a string in Python?

Tags: python, loops, replace

I am trying to write two procedures to replace matched strings in a string in python. 
And I have to write two procedures.

def matched_case(old new):
.........

note: inputs are two strings, it returns a replacement converter.

def replacement(x,another_string):
..........

note:inputs are a converter from previous procedure, and a string. It returns the result of applying the converter to the input string.

for example:

```
a = matched_case('mm','m')
print replacement(a, 'mmmm')
it should return m
```

another example:

```
R = matched_case('hih','i')
print replacement(R, 'hhhhhhihhhhh')
it should return hi
```

I am not sure how can I use loop to do the whole thing. Thanks so much for anyone can give a hint.

Comment: Your question  is not so clear...can you clean up a bit

Answer (score 3):

```
def subrec(pattern, repl, string):
    while pattern in string:
        string = string.replace(pattern, repl)
    return string
```

`foo('mm', 'm', 'mmmm')`  return `m`

`foo('hih', 'i', 'hhhhhhihhhhh')`  return `hi`

Comment: to mimic familiar `re.sub` signature and to point out that the substitution is recursive: `def subrec(pattern, repl, string): ...`

Comment: Thinking more about the loop, it can be simplified as **while src in a: a = a.replace(src, dst)** (no **if**, no **break**).

Comment: @shihongzhi OP wants that in two functions. IMO it is best to use a `lambda` like I have done below.

Answer (score 0):

Something on the lines of the below might help:

```
def matched_case(x,y):
    return x, lambda param: param.replace(x,y)

def replacement(matcher, s):
    while matcher[0] in s:
        s = matcher[1](s)
    return s

print replacement(matched_case('hih','i'), 'hhhhhhihhhhh')
print replacement(matched_case('mm','m'), 'mmmm')
```

OUTPUT:

```
hi
m
```

`matched_case(..)` returns a replacement-converter, so it is best represented using a [lambda](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda) (anonymous function to put it simply). This anonymous function wraps up the string to the found and the code that actually replaces it.