# Python deep reverse in a list

Tags: python, list, reverse

I have a nested list, and I need to reverse every element in the list. But I dont know whether the list is a list of list of list or not.
So example is:

```
p = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6]]]]
print deep_reverse(p)
#>>> [[[[6, 5], 4], 3, 2], 1]

q =  [1, [2,3], 4, [5,6]]
print deep_reverse(q)
#>>> [ [6,5], 4, [3, 2], 1]
```

What I have so far is:

```
def is_list(p):
    return isinstance(p, list)

def deep_reverse(a):
    a.reverse()
    for i in a:
        if is_list(i):
            i.reverse()
            print a
```

It works well for the second test, the q one, but doest work for the first test.
I am not sure do I need use a recursion to loop the whole thing? How can I modify my code? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you do need recursion. (Have you attempted to do so?)

Comment: Your function only goes 2 levels deep into the list. As dbaupp said, you need to utilize recursion. As a hint, your answer is correct except for 1 line ;)

Comment: for such a simple thing like `isinstance(p, list)` you don't need to disguise it in your own function

Comment: @dbaupp: I am not quite familar with recursion in python though. Could you give me a hint please?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: no , it is not a homework. It is just a sample that from my work, the data structure is similar to the examples above. I am new to python, so post the question here.

Comment: @JoelCornett: Could you please give me a hint about how to write the recursion part?

Comment: @MaggieMi: See ielashi's answer. There's a difference of one line from the code you provided.

Comment: So this question, and your other one ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845321/how-can-i-replace-certain-string-in-a-string-in-python) are from the Udacity ( http://www.udacity.com) CS 101 Final. I'm not a teacher or anything...but I wouldn't think the best way to understand computer science is to have people on stackoverflow answering your exam questions for you. So I guess you're right, it isn't a "homework" problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because if `i` is a list of lists, you don't `deep_reverse` the lists within `i`.

You only need to change one line of your code to the following:

```
def is_list(p):
    return isinstance(p, list)

def deep_reverse(a):
    a.reverse()
    for i in a:
        if is_list(i):
            deep_reverse(i)  # <=== This is what changed
            print a
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def deep_reverse(lst):
    try:
        if len(lst) > 1:
            return list(deep_reverse(item) for item in reversed(lst))
        return lst
    except TypeError:
        return lst
```

Comment: If you check the type in there you won't need exception handling: `return [i if type(i) != list else deep_reverse(i) for i in lst[::-1]]`. This should let you reverse with disparate types in the list.

Comment: @JeremyPridemore Don't ever check `type` like that, use `isinstance`

Comment: Use `reversed` instead of `[::-1]`

Comment: @jamylak: Thanks for the tip about the reversed, I forgot about that one.

Comment: @jamylak Thanks for the tips. I'm still learning Python, and using some SO questions for good problems to solve.

Comment: This will reverse anything that has a length, not just list. (The most obvious problem is if a list contains strings.)

Answer (score 1):

```
def deep_reverse(L):
    if L == []:
        return L
    elif type(L) == int:
        return L
    else:
        return deep_reverse(L[1:]) + [deep_reverse(L[0])]

>>> print deep_reverse(p)
[[[[6, 5], 4], 3, 2], 1]

>>> print deep_reverse(q)
[[6, 5], 4, [3, 2], 1]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Use `isinstance(..)` instead of `type(..) == ..`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def deep_reverse(L):
        for item in reversed(L):
            if isinstance(item,list):
                yield list(deep_reverse(item))
            else:
                yield item


>>> p = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6]]]]
>>> q =  [1, [2,3], 4, [5,6]]
>>> list(deep_reverse(p))
[[[[6, 5], 4], 3, 2], 1]
>>> list(deep_reverse(q))
[[6, 5], 4, [3, 2], 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
def is_list(p):
    return isinstance(p, list)
   
def deep_reverse(p):

 if p==[]:
    return p

 if not is_list(p[0]):
    return deep_reverse(p[1:])+[p[0]]
 
 else:
    return deep_reverse(p[1:])+[deep_reverse(p[0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def deep_reverse(ls):  
    for i in ls:  
        if type(i)==list:deep_reverse(i)  
    ls.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a suggestion :

```
def deep_reverse(lst):
    if isinstance(lst ,list):
        if sum(1 for x in lst if isinstance(x, list)) == 0:
                        lst = lst[::-1]
                        return lst
        else :
            lst = lst[::-1]
            lst = [deep_reverse(item) for item in lst]     
            return lst
    else:
         return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_list(p):
    return isinstance(p, list)

def deep_reverse(p):

 if p==[]:
    return p

 if not is_list(p):
    return p
 else:
    return deep_reverse(p[1:])+[deep_reverse(p[0])]
```

test ok.

Answer (score 0):

most elegant:

```
def deep_reverse(L):
    """ assumes L is a list of lists whose elements are ints
    Mutates L such that it reverses its elements and also 
    reverses the order of the int elements in every element of L. 
    It does not return anything.
    """
    # Your code here
    for i in L:
        try:
            deep_reverse(i)
        except:
            pass
    L.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going old school on this problem's butt:

```py
def deepReverse(L):
    """Input a list tot output a reversed form of it"""
    if not L:
        return []
    elif isinstance(L[-1], list):
        return [deepReverse(L[-1])] + deepReverse(L[0:-1])
        
    else:
        return [L[-1]] + deepReverse(L[0:-1])
```