# Reversing a list and all the sublists inside it

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, recursion

I have a problem where I'm asked to define a procedure to reverse a list and every sublist in it
For example:

```
p = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6]]]]
print deep_reverse(p)
>>> [[[[6, 5], 4], 3, 2], 1]
```

The tutor solution was the following:

```
def is_list(p):
    return isinstance(p, list)
def deep_reverse(p):
    if is_list(p):
        result = []
        for i in range(len(p) - 1, -1, -1):
            result.append(deep_reverse(p[i]))
        return result
    else:
        return p
```

I’m wondering if it is possible to define a separate procedure to reverse the lists (`reverse_list`) and implementing it inside the `deep_reverse` procedure.
I tried doing so, but failed
thanks

Comment: What exactly is the question, you can reverse a list with `l[::-1]`

Comment: A separate function for reversal is possible, but the code that is doing the reversal is not very "pythonic", i.e. there is a native function and syntax for reversing lists, so this code does not really show best practice.

Comment: Unclear what you mean, better show the failed attempt. Also, do you need a new structure or would it be ok to just reverse all existing lists?

Comment: Hmm, [10 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10859135/12671057) it was still an in-place task.

Comment: @mozway i want to reverse the list and if there are lists inside the list I want them to reverse too. Sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: @KellyBundy my searching method is flawed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here would be a simpler, IMO more pythonic, version of the code:

```
def deep_reverse(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        return [deep_reverse(e) for e in l[::-1]]
    else:
        return l
```

or, using a ternary conditional (less explicit IMO):

```
def deep_reverse(l):
    return [deep_reverse(e) for e in l[::-1]] if isinstance(l, list) else l
```

example:

```
deep_reverse([1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6]]]])
[[[[6, 5], 4], 3, 2], 1]
```

Comment: Didn't know about the [::-1] syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It is overkill to create a separate function for reversing a list, as there is already a native `reversed` function and also the `[::-1]` syntax.

Here is how you can use the `reversed` function -- which returns an iterator:

```
def deep_reverse(lst):
    return list(map(deep_reverse, reversed(lst))) if isinstance(lst, list) else lst
```